# Find last of match string automatically

Tags: php

I want to make id for entries as long as 7 digits.. 
while first entry is created, it will get id is 0000001
And my problem is i want to get id and add to 1 every time new entry is created..

I have a bunch of code and still confuse to implement it.

```
$str_rep = "0000123";
$str_rep2 = "0005123"; // My character string can be like this
$str_rep3 = "0009123"; // My character string can be like this

$match_number= array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); // I create array to do it automatically but it was not work.

// I do it manually
$get_str = strstr($str_rep, "1");
$get_str = strstr($str_rep2, "5");
$get_str = strstr($str_rep3, "9");

// Result
echo $get_str . "<br>";
echo $get_str2 . "<br>";
echo $get_str3 . "<br>";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this question I think you'd be better off first learning the fundamentals of PHP before asking for help with a specific problem. Try reading the first few chapters of the PHP manual, or get a book like this: http://www.amazon.com/PHP-Absolute-Beginners-Jason-Lengstorf/dp/1430224738/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1294028156&sr=8-1

Comment: In my examples i do it manually i want create it automatically guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` as:

```
$str_rep = "0000123";
$str_rep = sprintf("%07s",$str_rep+1);  // $str_rep is now "0000124"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str_pad()`](http://ttp://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
$input = 1;
echo str_pad($input, 7, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); // prints 0000001
$input++;
echo str_pad($input, 7, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); // prints 0000002
```